# Identifying dates of the form \d\d-\d\d-\d\d using regexner

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford regexNer alongwith ner in a pipeline. I want to identify strings of the form [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] (e.g., 27-02-16) as date, which ner identifies as a NUMBER. So, I defined a regex in a mapping file and gave it to regexner. But regexNer is not able to identify such strings as dates. The ner for these tokens is still NUMBER.
Following is the mapping file:

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}  date    NUMBER
```

I ensured that the columns are tab-separated. I tried several versions of this regex like \d\d-\d\d-\d\d and [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9], but none of them worked. Any pointers on where I can be wrong? I am using Stanford CoreNLP 3.7. Here the java code I am running.

```
Properties PROPS = new Properties();

PROPS.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner");
        StanfordCoreNLP PIPELINE = new StanfordCoreNLP(PROPS);
        PIPELINE.addAnnotator(
                new RegexNERAnnotator("/home/jyoti/workspace-jee/QA_Rest/src/main/resources/Gazetter.txt"));
```

I further investigated and found that the regex is not matching any string only if it consists wholly of integers. I tried prefixing it with alphabet and it worked (i.e., a\d\d-\d\d-\d\d matched a14-07-12).

Comment: @stanfordnlphelp, any pointers please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you running this, because your original rule works fine for me.

I issued this command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner -regexner.mapping date-rules.txt -file date-example.txt -outputFormat text
```

Comment: I am running it through java api. I added the code in the edit.

Comment: You need to remove the "addAnnotator" line and add a line that is PROPS.setProperty("regexner.mapping", "/path/to/rules-file.txt") before you build the pipeline...regexner is the annotator that uses the rules and regexner.mapping is the property that sets the rules file to be used